# Obscure compiler error when using a closure as 'state' in sequence(state:next:): function mis-use or Swift limitation?

Tags: swift, closures

**Background**

We may use closures as `inout` parameters:

```
func mutate(_ closure: inout () -> Int) {
    let num = closure()
    closure = { return 2*num }
}

var closure: () -> Int = { return 21 }
print(closure()) // 21
mutate(&closure)
print(closure()) // 42
```

**Issue**

However, when I attempt to use a closure as the (initial) `state` argument in the global [`sequence(state:next:)` function](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/2011998-sequence), I'm prompted with somewhat a strange error (not alike the usual "public errors) and a stack trace.

```
// dummy example not even making use of the state ('foo')
var i = 0
let seq = sequence(
    state: { () -> () in () },
    next: { (foo: inout () -> ()) -> Int? in
        i += 1
        guard i < 5 else { return nil }
        return i
})

// or
var i = 0
var baz: () -> () = {}
let seq = sequence(
    state: bar,
    next: { (foo: inout () -> ()) -> Int? in
        i += 1
        guard i < 5 else { return nil }
        return i
})
```

Compiling a project with the content as per above produce (among other things, trace etc):

> **Swift compiler error: Command failed due to signal: Illegal instruction: 4**
>
> `inout` writeback in abstraction difference thunk not yet implemented
>
> input value   `%1 = argument of bb0 : $*@callee_owned (@in ()) -> @out ()`
>
> output type   `$*@callee_owned () -> ()`

I can't really make much out of this myself, other than that it seems to be thrown [from swift/lib/SILGen/SILGenPoly.cpp](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/lib/SILGen/SILGenPoly.cpp#L1188)

**Question**

- Can we somehow use closures as the `state` in `sequence(state:next:)`, such that its me missing something above? Or is this some known (current) language limitation?

I'm using Xcode 8.1 / Swift 3.0.1.

Comment: I have no idea how to make it compile, but one can narrow it further down: Calling `func test(next: (inout () -> ()) -> ()) { }` with `test(next: { (foo: inout () -> ()) -> () in })` compiles. But if you make the function **generic:** `func test<State>(next: (inout State) -> ()) { }` then the compiler crashes if you call the function in the same way. – Of course the compiler should never crash, so that it worth a bug report.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the more minimal example, will post a bug report tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing @MartinR's comment to the question,

> *"... the compiler should never crash"*

so this is likely a bug, and a bug report has been filed:

- [SR-3450: Closure with an 'inout' closure argument crashes the compiler when supplied to generic function](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3450)